# How to create a separate STA thread for a WPF form that is inside of a dll and not a WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sta

I have a dll that contains a WPF form. This dll will be called by another WPF application, which unfortunately I can't touch it. The problem is that there is no Main method in my WPF form to place

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    //...
}
```

The exception is thrown right on the constructor of my class. How can I get around this STA problem in this case. Again, this is not a WPF application, but a WPF form that is places inside of a dll.

```
namespace VisualScannerTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for VisualScanner.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class VisualScanner :Window,IPeripheral<VisualScanner.VisualScannerSettings>
    {
        private VisualScannerSettings _settings;
        private readonly IEventManager _eventManager;


        public VisualScanner(IEventManager eventManager):base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _eventManager = eventManager;
        }


        private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             string input = InpuTextBox.Text;
             InpuTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            {
                _eventManager.GetEvent<PeripheralEvent>().Publish(new PeripheralEventData {RawData = input});
            }

        }


        public void Initialize(VisualScannerSettings settings)
        {
            _settings = settings;
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> RegisterImpulses()
        {
            yield break;
        }

        public string Type
        {
            get { return GetType().FullName; }
        }
         public sealed class VisualScannerSettings:PeripheralSettings
        {
            public string Data { get; set; }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you do something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15724526/612512)?

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to put it in:An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

Comment: Why is the calling application trying to create a UI object it on a non-UI thread?

Answer (score 1):

I would 1st suggest you turn the dll into another WPF application that has it's own thread then you need a different way to communicate with it - such as using another dll both applications reference or using some merhod of [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), e.g. a TCP Socket.

Alternatively you could try expose in the `dll` what needs to be called on the STA thread of the consumer. So you application could call it, e.g.:

```
CreateForm();
```

for example.

Though that may not work - you need to setup a few things to make WPF tick it is not just matter of using an STA thread:

1. Set the SetSynchronizationContext to a DispatcherSynchronizationContext

   SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));
2. Create a `System.Windows.Application()`
3. Load and add any XAML Resources with Application.LoadComponent()`.

   var resources = System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/Styles.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
   Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resources);
4. You would need to programmatically pump the `Dispatcher`:

   Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.PushFrame();

Comment: Would you please tell me how the Dispatcher solution works? because the exception, which is: :"An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." is thrown as soon as the code hits the constructor of my class. So, I have to do something before that point.

Comment: The "Dispatcher solution" still requires you to be calling from the STA thread - as the exception says - so once you are doing that (which you could do by calling the library method from you application) you may still have to go through the steps I outlined above for the "Dispatcher solution". Again I advise you do NOT go down this path - create a another WPF application instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You need to use the TaskScheduler. Important is to set the ApartmentState.

```
public static async Task Main()
{
  var taskScheduler = new SingleThreadTaskScheduler(ApartmentState.STA);
  var taskList = new List<Task>();

  var updateTask = Task.Run(InstallHelper.CheckForUpdatesAsync);
  updateTask.Wait();
  taskList.Add(updateTask);
  var tasks = await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(taskList.ToArray(), result => 
                    Task.Factory.StartNew( ()=>MyAppSynchronMethodToRunIn_STAThread, 
                    taskScheduler));
}
```